# php chaining method error and confusion

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning `PHP OOP`, but now I'm stuck with an error and confused regarding the chained method. Here is my code

```
<?php
    class Car {
        public $tank;

        public  function fill($float) {
            $this-> tank += $float;
            return $this;
        }


        public  function ride($float) {
            $miles = $float;
            $gallons = $miles/50;
            $this-> tank -= ($gallons);
            return $this;
        }
    }


    $bmw = new Car(); 
    $tank = $bmw -> fill(10) -> ride(40);// -> tank;
    echo "The number of gallons left in the tank: " . $tank . " gal.";
?>
```

Now the problem is when used to call the functions without calling the Public variable `tank` then it's showing the following error message.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Car could not be converted to
>   string in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\chain.php on line 33

In this case why should I call the public variable `tank` while I am calling the two functions? If I'm not assigning any value directly to the Public Variable `tank` then why should I call that variable..??

I am very confused with this

Comment: Your `ride()` method returns itself, so `$tank` is a reference to the `$bmw` object.

Comment: You can use magic method `__toString`, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: You have copied the code form the book, "the-essentials-of-object-oriented-php".
At the Chain Method Lesson it is stated that,
"In order for us to be able to perform the chaining, the methods should return the object and, since
we are inside the class, the methods should return the $this keyword."

You could use  __toString(), call individually or set a getter method.

Answer (score 5):

Your method `ride` returns an instance of the class `Car` so if you echo it you try to echo the existing class instance directly. You have two options now:

## __toString() magic function

**Inside of the class**

```
function __toString() {
    return $this->tank;
}
```

**The echo call**

```
echo "The number of gallons left in the tank: " . $tank . "gal.";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

### Implement a getter function

**Inside of the class**

```
function getRemainingGallons() {
    return $this->tank;
}
```

**The echo call**

```
echo "The number of gallons left in the tank: " . $tank->getRemainingGallons() . " gal.";
```

**Or edit the chained function**

```
$tank = $bmw -> fill(10) -> ride(40) -> getRemainingGallons();
```

Make sure to choose a clear name for your method so that you always know what it does.

Comment: Why not something with clearer intent like `getRemainingGallons()`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
$tank = $bmw -> fill(10) -> ride(40);// -> tank;
```

with

```
$bmw->fill(10);    
$bmw->ride(40);    
$tank = $bmw->tank;
```

And it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways,

1) Directly access public variable

```
$tank->tank
```

2) Create a getter method for this like

```
public function getVolume() {
    return $this->tank;
}
```

Then access this by following way

```
echo "The number of gallons left in the tank: " . $tank->getVolume() . " gal.";<br>
echo "The number of gallons left in the tank: " . $tank->tank . " gal.";
```